# Hasing a file bigger then RAM in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, hash

I am trying to hash a file using `crypto` in nodejs.
Here is what I have done yet.

```
// generate a hash from file stream
    var crypto = require('crypto'),
        fs = require('fs'),
        key = 'hehe';

    // open file stream
    var fstream = fs.createReadStream('path/to/file');
    var hash = crypto.createHash('sha512', key);
    hash.setEncoding('hex');

    // once the stream is done, we read the values
    fstream.on('end', function() {
        hash.end();
        // print result
        console.log(hash.read());
    });

    // pipe file to hash generator
    fstream.pipe(hash);
```

Everything works well, but I am wondering what will be if the file I want to hash will be bigger then my RAM?

Theoretically now the program should crash if the file will be bigger then RAM.
My current RAM is 10gb and I don't have a file bigger in size then 10gb to test.

Comment: It's a file _stream_, so the contents of the file will be streamed in blocks to the hashing utility. It will be fine for a file larger than what can fit in RAM.

Comment: @rafalio what do you mean by file stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting into simpler concept:

Your `fstream` is a stream reader, it will read your file per small blocks of fixed size, and your `hash` will be building sha512 hash string off small blocks of the file. Your program does not hold the entire file in ram, it reads small chunks of it, generate hash digest, evict them from ram and read the next chunks of data.

If you want to test this, generate your 10GB file `fallocate -l 10G 10gbtest.img` and run your script against this file.